# Libgdx & Android Studio: Label doesn't show any text

Tags: java, android, libgdx, label

I am trying to add a Label text to the screen but nothing seems to be showing up: This is the code that I have coded and below has the screen that I ended up with, I could still change all colours but nothing shows up

```
    import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Align;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;

public class FiraMain extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    private Skin mySkin;
    private Stage stage;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    int guides = 12;
    int rowHeight = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 12;
    int colWidth = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 12;

    Label.LabelStyle labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle();
    Skin mySkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/glassy-ui.json"));
    Label label = new Label("Text", mySkin);
    label.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / guides, rowHeight);
    label.setPosition(colWidth * 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - rowHeight * 6);
    stage.addActor(label);

}

  @Override
  public void render () {
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 0);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      batch.begin();
      batch.end();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose () {

   }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dT5G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by mistake you forgot to call draw method of stage.

```
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();  //<--  Call draw method of stage inside render, it calls draw on every actor in the stage 
    stage.act();
}
```

Also I like to recommend you to dispose all disposable element in your game.

```
@Override
public void dispose () {
    stage.dispose();
    mySkin.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}
```